# Google Charts API Line Chart - How do I display multiple values when hovering?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, linechart

When using google's line chart, if you hover over a point it gives you the information about that point. For example, if a point is at `x:3, y:50` and the y-axis is called inches, hovering over the points would look something like:

```
.----------.
|3         |
|Inches: 50|
`----------`
```

When I am getting my data, with each point is also stored an extra value. So my array looks like: `[[3, 50, 20], [4, 52, 22], [5, 54, 24]]` and when I hover I want it to look like this:

```
.----------.
|Time: 3   |
|Inches: 50|
|Extra: 20 |
`----------`
```

So the two questions that I have are these:

1. **How do I add the 'Time: ' label before my x-value?**
2. **How can I add my 3rd value to be displayed?**

Here is the code that I have. What this does is creates a second line instead of adding the data together. [**You can look here**](http://jsfiddle.net/pQsDZ/1/) to see what I mean. You can also hover over the points and see what I'm talking about with the hovering. I'm sure there is a simple way to do this and I am just missing something.

```
function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Time', 'Inches', 'Extra'],
      [  3   ,    50   ,    20  ],
      [  4   ,    52   ,    22  ],
      [  5   ,    54   ,    24  ]
    ]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
        draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                    width: 500, height: 400,
                    vAxis: {title: 'Inches', maxValue: 10},
                    hAxis: {title: 'Time'}}
        );
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. It's not my favorite because repeating data is not the most efficient way but in any case, it is a solution so I'll post it here.

The first problem came from the way I was creating my data table. `arrayToDataTable` is useful but it is limiting. So I went away from that. This allows me to add my own columns and be more descriptive when creating these columns. For example, and what is the key to this is assigning a `role`. So I created the first 2 columns that I will use to plot the chart, and then I added a third column with the type of `string` and the role of `tooltip`.

When I add the data to my chart now, for the third column, I pass exactly what I want to be displayed when I hover over a point. This is where the repeating data comes in. It's not such a big deal but I think that there is probably a better / more direct way out there. Anyways, [**here is a link to my new chart**](http://jsfiddle.net/pQsDZ/4/), and here is my code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Inches');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});

    data.addRow(['3', 50, 'Time: 3\n Inches: 50\n Extra: 20']);
    data.addRow(['4', 52, 'Time: 4\n Inches: 52\n Extra: 22']);
    data.addRow(['5', 54, 'Time: 5\n Inches: 54\n Extra: 24']);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
        draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                    width: 500, height: 400,
                    vAxis: {title: 'Inches', maxValue: 10},
                    hAxis: {title: 'Time'}}
        );
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this adding "focusTarget: 'category'" to options:

```
draw(data,{..., focusTarget: 'category'}
```